# Merging 2 dataframes row wise

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge 2 dataframes based on the row name in df1 and column name from df2? My goal is to add another row to df1 and to omit the values from df1 that are not present in df2. Is there a way to do this?

example:

```
df1 = 
time  A  B  C  D
val1
val2 
val3

df2 = 
name  fruit  
A     apple
B     banana
G     grape
F     fig

wanted=
fruit apple banana  ''
time   A      B      C
val1
val2
val3
```

I've tried using merge, but it only creates a new column. I have also looked at using multi indexing, but I couldn't figure it out. Please help. Thank you

Comment: Think you may want to research `melt()`

Comment: Hi, so you want to add a new column header above the one in `df1`?